# C++ Declaring Template <Class T> above int main()

Tags: c++, templates, program-entry-point

I have a template list in my main which has a template class object in it.

```
List<serviceInfo<T>> priceList;
```

In order for me to get it working, I will have to declare template  above my main

```
template <class T>
int main()
```

which will give me the following error:

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *main referenced in function
>   _*_tmainCRTStartup

Comment: You will never need a templated `main`. What are you trying to do? To make one, you have to *give* it a type.

Comment: By the way, [GCC is very explicit](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1AGyUZ%241).

Comment: Because I'm trying to create 2 List<serviceInfo<T>> list with different type of parameters.

Comment: @PamelaLufkin, How do you plan on getting those types? You can still create two different ones by instantiating it twice with two different types.

Comment: Actually what I mean is my 2 list will be like this
priceList(string, double, double, double)
timeList(string, int, int , int)
that is why I made serviceInfo a template class

Comment: How much are the types you give it going to differ? Will there always be 4? Will the first always be a string? Will the last three always be the same? Maybe it would help if we saw `serviceInfo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`main` should never be templated.

Instead, you should replace `T` in `List<serviceInfo<T>>` with an actual type.
If you want to have different types of `serviceInfo<T>` in your list, create several lists.

Comment: Yea, I tried creating 2 list like this List<serviceInfo<string, double, double, double>> priceList;
 List<serviceInfo<string, int, int, int>> durationList;

Comment: You only declared one templated argument, `T`. You are using 4! Change the declaration of your `serviceInfo` to `template<class T, class U, class V, class W>` if you want 4 template arguments.

Comment: Can I do it with template<string, Class T, Class U, Class A> ?

Comment: @Pamela my suggest is you should forget template for now, learn the basic c++ programming skills first